# Convert aplhanumeric string to numbers- NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, exception, parseint, numberformatexception

I have to get number 23 from string "a23". When below program is run, following error is seen.

```
public class GetIntFromString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "a23";

        int i = Integer.parseInt(str);

        System.out.println("Integer value= "+i);

        System.out.println("value= "+str);

    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For Input String: "a23"

at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString<NumberFormatException.java.48>
at java.lang.Integer.ParseInt<Integer.java.449>
at java.lang.Integer.ParseInt<Integer.java.499>
at GetIntFromString.main<GetIntFromString.java.9>
```

Comment: Do some research first, it is very easy. Integer.parseInt does not work for alphanumeric strings, you need to extract the number part from string and pass it to Integer.parseInt method.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove any non-digit characters ;)

```
System.out.println("Integer value= "+str.replaceAll("[^0-9]",""));
```

Answer (score 2):

The parseXXX() methods don't accept strings that aren't true to the type being requested - integer in this case. You're going to have to figure out a technique to locate the actual numeric part manually (or perhaps using regex).

Answer (score 2):

If your prefix letter is only going to be one character always, then try the following

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1));
```

Otherwise, you need a way to figure out the numeric part before calling parseInt

Answer (score 1):

You should call replaceAll on str, to remove every non numeric character. Parseint only accepts pure numeric strings.

Answer (score 0):

parsing method takes only numbers in string format. Otherwise it throws NumberFormatException.